# How to rename all specific filetypes of files within subfolders to name with same file extension but same file name

Tags: python, rename

I have 690 files within subfolders - the subfolders names need to stay the same but the .iso files within each subfolder needs to be renamed to game.iso - this is possible as each ISO is in its own folder (folder name cannot be changed)

I'm currently teaching myself Python3 but I'm really struggling with this.

Any help is appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27939282/python-rename-files-in-subdirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a script that achieves this. It does so recursively, and you run it by providing the root directory where you want to start working from. For example, I have the script saved as iso_rename: `./iso_rename <enter full path to start lookin for .iso files>`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import os, sys

dir = sys.argv[1]

def rename_iso(dir):
  items = os.scandir(dir)

  for item in items:
    if item.is_file() and item.name.endswith('.iso'):
      if item.name == 'game.iso':
        continue
      os.rename(item.path, os.path.join(dir, 'game.iso'))
    elif item.is_dir():
      rename_iso(item.path)

rename_iso(dir)
```

Comment: Thanks, 

I replaced dir = sys.argv[1] with dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) so i can just run in the root, works like a charm, thanks boss.

Comment: So accept the answer pretty please :)

Comment: IMO, the other answer is more elegant

Answer (score 1):

The "newer" [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) is helpful here.

A recursive glob can match all filenames by extension.

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> for p in Path().rglob('*.iso'):
...     print(p)
a/b/2.iso
a/b/c/d/3.iso
a/b/c/d/e/1.iso
```

The part before the extension is called the `stem` in pathlib terminology - you can modify this using `.with_stem()`

```
>>> for p in Path().rglob('*.iso'):
...     print(p.with_stem('game'))
a/b/game.iso
a/b/c/d/game.iso
a/b/c/d/e/game.iso
```

You can pass this directly to the `.rename()` method

```
for p in Path().rglob('*.iso'):
    p.rename(p.with_stem('game'))
```

Which will rename all of the files:

```
>>> for p in Path().rglob('*.iso'):
...     print(p)
a/b/game.iso
a/b/c/d/game.iso
a/b/c/d/e/game.iso
```